# How to prevent someone from acessing an html page, unless they have a login?

Tags: php, html

This is my doubt: I want to create a login page to acess an html page (I will use a form and a MySQL database for that).

The problem is, if someone knows the name of the html page, they can go there directly, without having to login, which is something I dont want. How do I prevent this?

Example: I have an **abc.html** page, and I create a **login.php** page to acess abc. But if I know the name and address of the abc page, I can just type on my naviagtion bar: **www.somesite/abc.html** , and I can go to the abc page without logging in.

Comment: [.htaccess](http://weavervsworld.com/docs/other/passprotect.html) may be a better route if it suits your needs

Comment: Not related to your question, but it will make your life easier if you switch to php for the other pages as well, `abc.php`, etc. so that the php will get executed by default.

Comment: The only way to protect `.html` files is if you use `.htaccess` or instruct Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you're unwilling to rename your webpage from `abc.html` to `abc.php`, the best option, as Peter mentions, is likely to use htaccess to require a password for the page (provided of course your webserver is running Apache).

By using this method, you don't need to create a `login.php` page and open yourself up to all sorts of vulnerabilities (most 'custom' login scripts that require passwords nearly always isn't written in a secure manner).

Here's how you'd go about creating a password protected page with htaccess:

#### Password protection with htaccess

1. Create both a `.htaccess` file in your root directory of your site, and a `.htpasswd` in the directory you'd *like to protect*
2. Edit the `.htaccess` file so it contains the following code:

> ```
> AuthType Basic
> AuthName "Some message to be displayed to the user"
> AuthUserFile /your/path/to/.htpasswd
> Require valid-user
> ```

3. Edit the `.htpasswd` file so it contains your list of credentials. These are line separated, so if you'd like more than one user to access it, simply add a new user on a new line. The syntax is as follows:

> ```
> username:password
> ```

4. The password should not be stored in plain text though. You'll need to use a htpasswd generator, [such as David Walsh's here](http://davidwalsh.name/htaccess-username-password-generator), to create an encrypted password.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options you could use.

Assuming you're using Apache as a webserver, you could configure it to require a password itself without having a separate login page (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html).

Otherwise you could on your login page use a `$_SESSION` variable once you validate the user (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) and then check for that on the `html` page and if it's not there then redirect.